Is it predetermined whether one will get married or not? If so, is the spouse and timing also predetermined
In Hindu philosophy, is it predetermined if one will get married, and if so, is the spouse and timing also predetermined? How does this align with the concepts of karma and free will in texts like the Bhagavad Gita and other scriptures?
It's a burning question in my head relating to free will and destiny.

Marriage and it's timing is predetermined and is predetermined according to our karma only

In shastras like devi bhagavatam it is said No soul is independent; every one is under the effects of one’s own Karma. The Pundits that have realised the Truth, say that Karma is of three kinds, Accumulated, Present, and Prârabdha? This whole world is due to Kâla (Time), Karma (action) and Svabhâva (Nature); unless the proper time comes, even the Devas cannot kill men. The men are killed on account of some cause, immediate; but the Great Time is the real Destroy
